# How do we determine what's causing queries to MS Access DB through MS ODBC driver to fail in a C++ unmanaged environment?

Tags: c++, odbc, ms-access-2007

I'm trying to debug a client's application.
The application is built in MSVC (unmanaged) C++.
It connects to an MS Access DB (through ODBC).

When the MS Access DB is located on a local drive, all queries submitted
via the ODBC work fine to completion.

When the DB is located on a network drive, we run into issues.
It seems that all queries which are "Select" based (as in "Select * from FOO) return
successfully.

When we attempt to push a query through that either deletes, inserts or updates data, 
the ODBC call fails. The call doesn't return any particularly useful information. It returns -1 as the result (indicating failure). I've examined the handle (SQL_HANDLE_ENV, SQL_HANDLE_DBC, SQL_HANDLE_STMT) to see if there was additional error information associated with the failure.

For instance, when we attempt to delete, the error message we get back is:
"[Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Could not delete from specified tables."

We are having a difficult time figuring out what the issue is. Is there a way we can get more useful information regarding the error (ODBC Trace, etc)?

It's odd that simple selects seem to work fine while anything that adds/deletes/modifies data seems to fail.

What's the best strategy for debugging this?
Does anyone have any ideas that might help us hone in on the issue(s)?

Are these symptoms of an user/privilege accessibility issue?

Comment: Do you have write permission on the access file when it's on the network share?

Comment: Sounds like Chis is right.  Read-only connections to the db would explain the behavior you described.  You need read-write privilege for the db file itself, obviously.  Also the connecting user must be able to create a lock file (.ldb for an .mdb, or .laccdb for an .accdb) if one is not already present.  If a lock file is present the connecting user must be able to modify it.  If neither of those conditions is satisfied, the connection will be read-only.